# Is there a Graph API for looking up the page id of a public page for use in publishing a post with @mentions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch a list of pages I can tag.

My app is in Live mode (currently being used)
I have approved advanced access (went through FB Approval) to:

- the Page Mentions Feature,
- pages_read_engament,
- pages_manage_posts,
- pages_show_list,

I do NOT have

- Page Public Metadata Access
- Page Public Content Access

I tried using the following endpoints in the Graph API Explorer,

`/{page-id or 'me'}/likes` which used to return the ids of pages that had liked the page I am posting from. I was previously able to use that list to source the ids to use the @mentions feature. Now it returns:

> "error": {
> "message": "Permissions error",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 200,
> "error_subcode": 2069033,
> "is_transient": false,
> "error_user_title": "Unavailable Feature On New Page Experience",
> "error_user_msg": "The corresponding UI feature of this API is deprecated or not available for the new Pages experience.",
> "fbtrace_id": "-removed-"
> }

`/pages/search?q=Facebook` which returns

> "error": {
> "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 10,
> "fbtrace_id": "-removed-"
> }

I have tried both using my User Token, and using the Page Token for a page I'm an admin of.
I've tried setting up a test app in Dev mode (no FB approval permissions granted).

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 'Page Public Metadata Access' or 'Page Public Content Access'  features enabled to search like that `/pages/search?q=Facebook`. To get approval for any of these features (they substitute each other) you have to show how you would use it and how you will use info received from search.

Also it is very important to use App token, but not User or Page tokens.